# Custom tags in TinyMCE WYSWYG

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have an application which help our user to format the email template. A sample email template looks like this:

```
Dear <FirstName> <LastName>:    

Thank you for your entry <Title> and your order number is <OrderID>....
```

These are saved in our database as Text. The issue is when i try to load this text in simple Textarea it works fine when i try to display this text in TinyMCE editor textarea it cuts off when it see the first "<" and display something like this:

```
Dear :    

Thank you for your entry and your order number is ....
```

TinyMCE dose not render the tags. i dont know how to render the custom tags and they are not `<abc> </abc>` tags. Our system will replace the `"<SomeValue>"` with the actual value based on the tag and send the email to the client.

I tried replacing the `"<" and ">"` to `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"` and its not working. I also tried them replacing it to `"<code>&lt;" and "&gt;</code>"` before i bind the textarea but that is not working either. I have added "code" plugin while declaring my TinyMCE in javascript. Do i need anything else, any specially "entity_encoding"? I tried "raw" and "html" nothings works.
here is my javascript

```
 <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
           
            entity_encoding: "html",
            plugins: "code",
            toolbar: 'code'
        });
    </script>
```

Any help is appreciated as i have spend two days searching the web and trying bunch of things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want TinyMCE to treat these elements like HTML tags you need to define them as custom tags:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#custom_elements

An alternative which may take less effort to setup is to use another syntax (e.g. `{first_name}`) along with marking that text as non-editable so that TinyMCE treats the entire string like one "character" in the UI.